# How do I use StreamReader to add split lines to a dictionary?

Tags: c#, split, streamreader

I am trying to read a .txt file with StreamReader, split lines and add them to a Dictionary, but when I debug it, it doesn't work because the first line is null and it doesn't go further. How do I define string fullLine for it to work?

```
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"N:\Desktop\krew.txt");
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"N:\Desktop\newKrew.txt");
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string fullLine = "";


        while (fullLine != null)
        {
            fullLine = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] wholeLine = fullLine.Split('\t');
            dict.Add(wholeLine[0], wholeLine[1]);
```

Comment: Uh, how could `fullLine` be null on the first run? You set it to an empty string the previous line, which is not null.

Comment: `ReadLine()` returns null only when it reaches the end of the file. Your file has content, and you didn't typo the path? Your program is able to access your different drive letter?

Comment: It might just be easier to use `File.ReadAllLines(..)` instead of a StreamReader

Comment: And if you intend to continue using StreamReader, take a look at the [Microsoft Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8#examples), which uses a `using`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the bellow. This sets the line variable to each line in the file

```
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"N:\Desktop\krew.txt");
    Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string line;

    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] wholeLine = line.Split('\t');
        dict.Add(wholeLine[0], wholeLine[1]);
    }
```

Comment: why doesn't this work with assigning fullLine = sr.ReadLine(); and does without it?

Comment: @Wurfv_ You've got to asign the variable inside the while loop condition. That way it sets it before it checks if it is null

Answer (score 2):

You can try *Linq* and let .Net open (and `Dispose`) `Stream`s, `Reader`s for you

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 Dictionary<string, string> dict = File
   .ReadLines(@"N:\Desktop\krew.txt")
   .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) // to be on the safe side
   .Select(line => line.Split('\t'))
   .ToDictionary(items => items[0], items => items[1]);
```

To add into *existing* dictionary:

```
 var lines = File
   .ReadLines(@"N:\Desktop\krew.txt")
   .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
   .Select(line => line.Split('\t'));

 foreach (var wholeLine in lines)
   dict.Add(wholeLine[0], wholeLine[1]);
```

If you *insist* on `StreamReader`, you can implement a simple `for` loop:

```
// Do not forget to Dispose it
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"N:\Desktop\krew.txt")) {
  // if fullLine == null, sr is at the end and can't read any more lines
  for (string fullLine = sr.ReadLine(); fullLine != null; fullLine = sr.ReadLine()) {
    string[] wholeLine = fullLine.Split('\t');
    dict.Add(wholeLine[0], wholeLine[1]);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off writing the loop like this:

```
while (true)
{
    string fullLine = sr.ReadLine();

    if (fullLine == null)
        break;

    string[] wholeLine = fullLine.Split('\t');
    dict.Add(wholeLine[0], wholeLine[1]);
    ...
```

As you have written the loop right now, `fullLine` will become null at the end of the file and then the `fullLine.Split('\t');` will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

I suspect that is what you mean when you say `first line is null and it doesn't go further`. It can't actually be the *first* line causing the issue, since you initialise `fullLine` to "", but I think that is the underlying issue.

Comment: A .txt can't have true 'null' values in between lines. Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't they read in as /n with streamReader?

Comment: @xTwisteDx: file can't have `null` lines but *empty* `""` ones

Comment: @xTwisteDx As [the documentation for `StreamReader.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.8) states: `The returned value is null if the end of the input stream is reached`, so this is how the loop detects the EoF condition.

Answer (score 1):

Use the .Peek() method in your while loop to read to the end of the file. It should get past your first line is empty.

> - Null is no the same thing as ""
> - Peek() will check for the next character and it the line is `blank` it will return `""`.
> - If you have lines on line 2 through X then the blank lines are not null, therefore .Peek() will return -1. Check out the documentation on it.

.Peek() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.peek?view=netframework-4.8

```
//Doing it in a Using statement to properly dispose of the StreamReader
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
            {

                while (sr.Peek() > -1) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like this

```
while ((fullLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] wholeLine = fullLine.Split('\t');
            dict.Add(wholeLine[0], wholeLine[1]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't *fully* reliant on *having* to use StreamReader..

```cs
    string[] read = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
    for (int i = 0; i < read.Length; i++)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(read[i])
            continue;
        string[] lineArray = read[i].Split(new [] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        dict.Add(lineArray[0], lineArray[1]);
    }
```